# anyone can help me how to decrypt this lua

Tags: lua

```lua
key="mikacommunityscript"local a=load((function(b,c)function bxor(d,e)local f={{0,1},{1,0}}local g=1;local h=0;while d>0 or e>0 do h=h+f[d%2+1][e%2+1]*g;d=math.floor(d/2)e=math.floor(e/2)g=g*2 end;return h end;local i=function(b)local j={}local k=1;local l=b[k]while l>=0 do j[k]=b[l+1]k=k+1;l=b[k]end;return j end;local m=function(b,c)if#c<=0 then return{}end;local k=1;local n=1;for k=1,#b do b[k]=bxor(b[k],string.byte(c,n))n=n+1;if n>#c then n=1 end end;return b end;local o=function(b)local j=""for k=1,#b do j=j..string.char(b[k])end;return j end;return o(m(i(b),c))end)({5516,8542,9551,10042,6683,9468,5746,7170,8040,8999,8665,9962,10664,7255,8728,7666,7922,6403,6223,7121,9450,5928,5362
```

also its actually got 50k word anyone can help me with this? or is there any program thats can help with decrypting xD

Comment: replace `load` with `print`

Comment: sir egor why my lua.exe wont fit all codes? is there any vid thats help to do change load and print? i really wanted learn decrypt codes